# How to increase performance of foreach loop?

Tags: c#, winforms, foreach

How to *increase performance* (it takes about **10** seconds) of this *foreach* loop

```
foreach (var item in pList)
{
    var foundedItem = source.FirstOrDefault(x => x.LongRecordId == item.LongRecordId);
    if (foundedItem != null && !selectionList.Contains(foundedItem))
    {
        foundedItem.Readonly = pReadonly;
        selectionList.Add(foundedItem);
    }
}
```

Comment: Increasing performance is not an easy task. But maybe you could try to use the actual class for your `item` instead of `var`.

Comment: use for loop instead.

Comment: The problem might be your `selectionList.Contains(foundedItem)`. I don't know how complex your item is and how many items you store in that list. But you might wanna try a `Dictionary` instead.

Comment: the bottleneck may be the LINQ on `source`. what is the typical relation of numbers of items in `pList` as compared to `source`? precomputing either into a dictionary can be one approach. do some profiling to really find out (supposing you mean the performance including the loop body code, not just that of the `pList` iterator, which you don't show)

Comment: Exactly what I've said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case `source` as well as `pList` are long, you may try converting `source` into a `Dictionary`:

```
 // Provinding that all LongRecordId are distinct
 var dict = source
    .ToDictionary(item => item.LongRecordId, item => item);

 ...

 foreach (var item in pList) {
   MyRecord foundItem = null; //TODO: Put the right type here

   // Instead of O(N) - FirstOrDefault we have O(1) TryGetValue
   if (dict.TryGetValue(item.LongRecordId, out foundItem)) {
     foundItem.Readonly = pReadonly;
     selectionList.Add(foundItem);
   } 
 }
```

**Edit:** In case you want to ensure that `selectionList` contains *distinct* items only (see Ferhat Sayan's comment) try `HashSet`

```
 ...

 HashSet<MyRecord> selectedHash = new HashSet<MyRecord>(selectionList);

 foreach (var item in pList) {
   MyRecord foundItem null; //TODO: Put the right type here

   // Instead of O(N) - FirstOrDefault we have O(1) TryGetValue
   if (dict.TryGetValue(item.LongRecordId, out foundItem)) {
     foundItem.Readonly = pReadonly;
     selectedHash.Add(foundItem);
   } 
 }

 selectionList = selectedHash.ToList();
```

Comment: This example is missing the check if that item is already in selectionList, which could be a bottleneck aswell. But yah, it should lead to the right direction.

Comment: @Ferhat Sayan: if we want to ensure that `selectionList` contains distinct items only we can try `HashSet<T>`

Comment: thank you it very increase performance. Old version List open 10 second now 1 second this very helpful for me

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to profile that piece of code.

I guess the most time consuming call is the FirstOrDefault-Extension Method.

To use for instead of foreach is unlikely to grant you much if any performance gains.

Most probably your problems stems from your context variables, maybe a very large source list?

Overall, this code section is maybe not the best place to look for performance improvements. If this is the only place, you should think about a redesign.

If you have very large lists and do not fear concurrency issues you could go the parallel or multi-processing route. [parallel.foreach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991604(v=vs.110).aspx) is a cheap way to do some tests.

The use of a Dictionary instead of a List should speedup things. If you go with a HashSet (to yield the benefit of uniqunes) be aware to implement a proper IEqualityComparer, or you could even [lose performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46142734/why-is-hashsetpoint-so-much-slower-than-hashsetstring) when you add a huge number of items relying on the DefaultComparer.

Comment: It has nothing to do with `FirstOrDefault` IMO.

Comment: I don't think so. If you set up mock code with lists like shown here and profile it, you will see that FirstOrDefault is one of the most time consuming calls.