# HashSet: Why valueType.Equals(Object) is so slow

Tags: c#, .net, performance, hashset, cyclic-reference

Having this method:

```
public void RunFD(object fileObj, ISet<object> visited)
{
    if (!visited.Add(fileObj)) return;

    if (fileObj is IEnumerable enumerablFileObj )
    {
        foreach (var aFileObj in enumerablFileObj.OfType<object>())
        {
            RunFD(aFileObj , visited);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        AddToFolder(fileObj);
    }
}
```

fileObj is a simple object that can contain a string or custom object. The scenario where Parent1 -> child -> Parent1 may occur, hence the use of the HashSet named visited. Here, Parent1 refers to the exact same instance as the other Parent1.

Although this method is functioning as expected, I noticed it took significantly long to execute. Surprisingly, the bulk of the execution time was spent on visited.Add(fileObj).

During execution, the most time-consuming operation was observed within HashSet.AddIfNotPresent -> ObjectEqualityComparer.Equals -> ValueType.Equals(Object), which accounted for 95% of the total execution time of my method.

I am puzzled as I anticipated the time complexity for HashSet to be generally O(1), merely checking if the reference object is the same as the other (which aligns with my requirement).

Considering that I have numerous types of classes for fileObj, should I override the Equals method for all of them? Is there a more efficient way to check if the object is the same?

I tried to find another solution, but the only one that came up is to overload the Equals and GetHashCode methods of the object. However, this is very painful as I have many possible objects for this method..

Comment: Somewhat related questions: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46142734/why-is-hashsetpoint-so-much-slower-than-hashsetstring "Why is HashSet<Point> so much slower than HashSet<string>?") and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39391107/why-are-hashsets-of-structs-with-nullable-values-incredibly-slow "Why are HashSets of structs with nullable values incredibly slow?"). Also [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/performance-implications-of-default-struct-equality-in-c/) Microsoft article. Quick suggestion: use `record struct` instead of plain `struct`.

Comment: `if the reference object is the same as the other` If it's using `ValueType` then they are NOT reference types.

Comment: Side note: `enumerablFileObj.OfType<object>()` is redundant. `IEnumerable` is basically the same as `IEnumerable<object>`.

Comment: What is 'significantly long'? It makes sense that 95% are spent on `visited.Add` (which calls `AddIfNotPresent` internally), because that's the expensive operation there. But depending on the total execution time, 95% might still be very small. Also, Big-O-notation only says how the algorithm scales with size. How many objects are you adding? Are they reference or value types?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and provide a [mre].

Comment: Why are you handing around `object`s anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why valueType.Equals(Object) is so slow

One of the potential problems to be aware of is that [`ValueType.Equals` can use reflection](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/ValueType.cs,49). If value type does not override equality members and for example contains reference type fields/properties (see the list in [this github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/20954#issuecomment-733944969)) it will use the reflection to perform the operation:

```cs
// if there are no GC references in this object we can avoid reflection
// and do a fast memcmp
if (CanCompareBitsOrUseFastGetHashCode(RuntimeHelpers.GetMethodTable(obj))) // MethodTable kept alive by access to object below
{
    return //...
}
 
FieldInfo[] thisFields = GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

for (int i = 0; i < thisFields.Length; i++)
{
    object? thisResult = thisFields[i].GetValue(this);
    object? thatResult = thisFields[i].GetValue(obj);
    // ...
}
```

Which obviously is relatively costly operation.

Mitigations - define custom `GetHashcode` and `Equals` on the struct or provide custom `IEqualityComparer` comparer to the set.

Another point worth investigating is amount of the time the `Equals` is invoked. But this would require a full reproducer. `O(1)` is achieved with "good" hash function which results in collisions occurring rarely which may not be the case for your data (or just your data has a lot of duplicate items).

Answer (score -1):

If you only need o check for reference equality, use a custom equality comparer that uses ReferenceEquals:

```
public class ReferenceEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T> where T : class
{
    public static IEqualityComparer<T> Default { get {return new ReferenceEqualityComparer<T>();}}

    public bool Equals(T x, T y){ return ReferenceEquals(x, y); }
    public int GetHashCode(T obj) { return RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(obj); }
}

var visited = new HashSet<object>(ReferenceEqualityComparer<object>.Default);
```