# Explanation for nested decimals behaviour in ValueType GetHashCode/Equals implementation

Tags: c#, .net, equality, gethashcode, .net-4.7.1

I was scratching my head over an unexpected failing comparison between two instances of a custom struct. I hope someone can either point me to reference source or documentation, or confirm whether this is a bug!

Distilling the issue gets something like the following:

```
public readonly struct TwoDecimals
{
    public readonly decimal First;
    public readonly decimal Second;
    public TwoDecimals(decimal first, decimal second)
    {
        this.First = first;
        this.Second = second;
    }
}

public void Main()
{
    var withoutTrailingZero = new TwoDecimals(42m, 42m);
    var withTrailingZero = new TwoDecimals(42.0m, 42m);
    var equal = withoutTrailingZero.Equals(withTrailingZero); // true
    var equalHashCodes = withoutTrailingZero.GetHashCode() == withTrailingZero.GetHashCode(); // false!
}
```

This is a problem, because if `Equals` is true, `GetHashCode` should definitely return the same value.

I'm not overriding either of `Equals` or `GetHashCode`, so the custom struct should get the default `ValueType` implementation, which may be platform-specific. But reading in the reference source [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/valuetype.cs) I see a comment with this claim:

> Our algorithm for returning the hashcode is a little bit complex.  We look for the first non-static field and get it's [sic] hashcode.

Evidently that is not true, since `42.0m` and `42m` have the same hashcode, despite having different bits.

It seems as if, instead, it is falling back to using the bits for some reason. Unfortunately that method is `extern` and I'm not sure how to find the/a source.

The reference source *does* have an implementation of `Equals`, which uses reflection to compare each field of the struct. But first, it does this check

```
// if there are no GC references in this object we can avoid reflection 
// and do a fast memcmp
if (CanCompareBits(this))
    return FastEqualsCheck(thisObj, obj);
```

`FastEqualsCheck`, presumably, just compares the bits. In my case, it must not be using this fast check, because the bits are definitely different, but I suspect that something similar may be happening in the implementation for `GetHashCode`.

---

I also tried analogous cases using `double`s (`0.0d` and `-0.0d` which have different bits but the same hashcode and are considered 'equal') and `float`s. The behaviour *still* wasn't as expected, but in a different way! This time, the hashcodes were once again different (and not, as suggested in that code comment, equal to the hashcode of the first field). But this time, the `Equals` method returns `false`, so at least it is consistent.

Comment: This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3842515/5181199 seems to partially explain what's going on, although it's outside the scope of the given question!

Comment: That answer seems to explicitly answer this one, particularly the last part. Given that answer - basically it's using a bitwise representation, which is a bug, I'm not sure what else could be added to an answer to *this* question. Of course the preferred fix here is to override Equals/GetHashCode yourself and also implement `IEquatable<TwoDecimals>`, but I do appreciate the curiosity.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926776/how-does-native-implementation-of-valuetype-gethashcode-work

Comment: It seems like the answer to this question is hidden as a 'bonus fun fact' in answers to other related questions. I'd love to see some real documentation, or a known bug note.