# Why should I *not* override GetHashCode()?

Tags: c#, java, .net, hash

My [search for a helper to correctly combine constituent hashcodes for `GetHashCode()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18065251/c-sharp-equivalent-of-java-guavas-objects-hashcode-for-combining-constit) seemed to garner some hostility. I got the impression from the comments that some C# developers don't think you should override `GetHashCode()` often - certainly some commenters seemed to think that a library for helping get the behaviour right would be useless. Such functionality was considered useful enough in Java for the [Java community to ask for it to be added to the JDK](http://marxsoftware.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/jdk-7-new-objects-class.html), and it's [now in JDK 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#hash%28java.lang.Object...%29).

Is there some fundamental reason that in C# you don't need to - or should definitely not - override `GetHashCode()` (and correspondingly, `Equals()`) as often as in Java? I find myself doing this often with Java, for example whenever I create a type that I know I want to keep in a `HashSet` or use as a key in a `HashMap` (equivalently, .net `Dictionary`).

Comment: You should override GetHashCode() when creating types that represent values.

Comment: @Slaks such as `int`, `double` and `Point`?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907372/why-does-c-sharp-not-implement-gethashcode-for-collections

Comment: @bacar the question is why is your code (seemingly) so fond of Dictionaries to begin with.

Comment: @SLaks my guess was that .net's value types provide a decent GetHashCode for you and there should be little need to provide your own, but I thought I'd see if the community has a more comprehensive answer.

Comment: I would love to hear #Jon's and #Eric's thoughts on this.

Comment: @HighCore: I've added mine to the original question. I'm not going to add an answer here, as it's not really an ideal question for SO at the moment - it's not really specific enough, to be honest.

Comment: @HighCore: `Dictionary<,>` is an incredibly useful type... not that it's the only use for overriding Equals/GetHashCode. It's often useful to be able to create a set of distinct elements, too. I don't think there's any reason to suggest that the OP *overuses* dictionaries, as you seem to be implying.

Comment: Deleted my answer, but two thoughts: in .NET, the cases where you *need* to implement this is the small % of a small % - so the "why not?" is "because you don't need to". But it seems possible it could also relate quite tightly to mutability / immutability; .NET objects are usually mutable, and custom GetHashCode implementations on a mutable type can be dangerous

Comment: Do you need two identical objects to be equal?   In addition I always override hash if the object has a natural static key.

Comment: @bacar: Actually, value types provide a very poor implementation of `GetHashCode()`.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182276.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**C# has built-in value types which provide value equality, whereas Java does not.** So writing your own hashcode in Java may be a necessity, whereas doing it in C# may be a premature optimisation.

It's common to write a type to use as a composite key to use in a Dictionary/HashMap. Often on such types you need [value equality (equivalence) as opposed to reference equality(identity)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd183752.aspx), for example:

```
IDictionary<Person, IList<Movie> > moviesByActor; // e.g. initialised from DB
// elsewhere...
Person p = new Person("Chuck", "Norris");
IList<Movie> chuckNorrisMovies = moviesByActor[p];
```

Here, if I need to create a new instance of Person to do the lookup, I need `Person` to implement value equality otherwise it won't match existing entries in the Dictionary as they have a different identity.

To get value equality, you need an overridden `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()`, in both languages.

C#'s structs (value types) [implement value equality](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dts52z7.aspx) for you (albeit a potentially inefficient one), and provide a consistent implementation of `GetHashCode`. This may suffice for many people's needs and they won't go further to implement their own improved version unless performance problems dictate otherwise.

Java has no such built-in language feature. If you want to create a type with value equality semantics to use as a composite key, you must implement equals() and correspondingly hashCode() yourself. (There are third-party helpers and libraries to help you do this, but nothing built into the language itself).

I've described C# value types as 'potentially inefficient' for use in a Dictionary because:

- [The implementation of `ValueType.Equals` itself can sometimes be slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841602/why-is-valuetype-gethashcode-implemented-like-it-is/3842515#3842515). This is used in Dictionary lookups.
- The implementation of `ValueType.GetHashCode`, whilst correct, can yield many collisions leading to very poor Dictionary performance also. Have a look at [this answer to a Q by Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12657348/new-keyvaluepairuint32-uint32i-j-gethashcode-high-rate-of-duplicates), which demonstrates that `KeyValuePair<ushort, uint>` appears to *always yield the same hashCode*!

Answer (score 0):

If your object represents a value or type, then you SHOULD override the GetHashCode() along with Equals. I never override hash codes for control classes, like "App". Though I see no reason why even overriding GetHashCode() in those circumstances would be a problem as they will never be put in a position to interfere with collection indexing or comparisons.

Example:

```
public class ePoint : eViewModel, IEquatable<ePoint>
{
    public double X;

    public double Y;

    // Methods

    #region IEquatable Overrides

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(obj, null)) { return false; }

        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) { return true; }

        if (!(obj is ePoint)) { return false; }

        return Equals((ePoint)obj);
    }

    public bool Equals(ePoint other)
    {
        return X == other.X && Y == other.Y;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (int)Math.Pow(X,Y);
    }

    #endregion
```

Comment: Thanks. This is just as true of Java as of C#. It doesn't explain if there is a particular reason that this is required less often in C# vs Java.

Comment: If its the same, then in what other circumstances does java require it?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a [helper class](http://blog.slaks.net/2010/12/simplifying-value-comparison-semantics.html/) to implement `GetHashCode()`, `Equals()`, and `CompareTo()` using value semantics from an array of properties.